# Input type number in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-class

I have a input type number in AngularJS as follows...

```
<input type="number"></input>
```

I want to achieve the following:

- If user enters a positive value, it should display the same font and color
- If the user displays a negative value, it should display font color in red indicating it is a negative number

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this.

**HTML**

`<input type="number" ng-class="{negative: amount < 0, positive: amount > 0}" ng-model="amount"/>`

**CSS**

```
.negative {
   color: red;
}
.positive {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi John, this works well. Wat if i have 2 classes. one class for positive value and one for negative value. How can i achieve that situation ?

Comment: Patrick, I have edited my answer to account for positive values as well.  All you need to do is add a new condition to ng-class and also create an additional class to reflect that in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" ng-change="amountChanged()" ng-style="myStyle.color" ng-model="amount"/>

$scope.myStyle= {};
$scope.amountChanged = function () {

   if($scope.amount < 0)
   {
      $scope.myStyle.color= {"color":"green"};
   }
   else
   {
      $scope.myStyle.color= {"color":"blue"};
   }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: instead of ng-style, can i use ng-class and assign a class directly ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input type="number" ng-model="number">
    <label ng-show="number > 0" style="color:green;">You are Correct</label>
    <label ng-show="number < 0" style="color:red;">Your number is negative</label>
```